# Rstudioでgitが使用できません

Tags: git, r

windows10
RStudio 1.2.1335 
R 3.6.0
git 2.21.0.windows.1

Rstudioでgit操作を行おうとした際，commitできるファイルが存在するもgitタブ上に表示されません．
gitタブ上の再表示やcommitボタンを押したらエラーのポップアップが表示されますが，文字化けしていて読むことができません．
どうしたら解決するでしょうか．

Answer (score 1):

日本語Windowsネイティブで動かすのは、それ自体が目的(Windowsアプリ開発)なので無ければ推奨できません。

データサイエンティストとして、RとRStudioを使いたいのであれば、
docker イメージ ( rocker/tidyverse ) を使用しましょう。

docker for windows をインストールしたら、

```
docker run -p 8787:8787 rocker/tidyverse
```

と打って少し待つだけで最新のRとコンパイル済みの各種パッケージが起動します。
devtools などを使う場合でも、一番トラブルが少ない方法です。
(殆どのRのコア開発者はUnixを前提にしています。docker を使うとWindows上でも純粋なLinux環境が再現出来ます)